# Install multiple versions of the BlackBerry device simulator

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I have to download the simulator installer package.  This is the package that will download and install multiple versions of the BlackBerry Smartphone simulator.  Can any one please tell me where can I find it and how can I use it to install multiple versions of the simulators for BlackBerry SDK 6.0?

Answer (score 2):

RIM has a page for finding various [BlackBerry Smartphone Simulators](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/resources/simulators.jsp).

There are download options to select a specific simulator by device & OS.

After download just run the installer.